# I was getting a error on data structure question and unable to identify

Tags: visual-c++

****The question is { WAP to demonstrate malloc(),calloc() and realloc() function for dynamic memory allocation}****

> **Source Code-**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int  main()
{
  int n,i,*p,n1;
  char ch;
   cout<<"Enter total elements ";
   cin>>n;
   p=(int*) malloc (p*sizeof(int));
   /* p=(int*)calloc(p,sizeof(int)); */
   if(p==NULL)
   {
     cout<<"Memory allocation failed\n";
     exit(1);
   }
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
     cout<<"Enter the element ";
     cin >> *(p+i);
   }
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
     cout<<*(p+i);
   }
   cout<<"Enter new size ";
   cin>>n1;
   p=(int*)realloc(p,sizeof(int));
   if(p==NULL)
   {
     cout<<"Memory allocation failed\n";
     exit(1);
   }
   for(i=n;i<n1;i++)
   {
     cout<<"Enter the element ";
     cin >>*(p+i);
   }
   for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
   {
     cout<<*(p+i);
   }
   free(p);
   return(0);
}
```

> **Error code line according to visual studio code**

p=(int*) malloc (p*sizeof(int));

> **Error Message, I was getting-**

expression must have arithmetic or unscoped enum type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
p*sizeof(int)
```

You should multiply sizeof(int) and some number, but not 'p' - pointer value.

```
int size = 20; 
p=(int*) malloc (size * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: thanks for help, I just use the size=0 which performs it perfectly!!